# Only Allow switch page if jQuery Mobile Switch is on YES

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Hi i just want to build a Form Switch from jQuery Mobile where the user have to select all to YES to come to the next page - so he can click the button.
If on of the 3 is on No, he should get a error message that tells him (only Display the name without the witch_) is needed to be set to YES, as a Popup if he try to click on a Link

This is the sample code for a switch

```
    <label for="switch_ Documents/Preflight Inspection">Select slider:</label>
<select name="slider" id="flip-a" data-role="slider">
    <option value="off">Off</option>
    <option value="on">On</option>
</select>
```

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/switch/

Would be great if someone could help me

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Attrc/

```
//bind event handler to the form for the submit event
$('form').bind('submit', function () {

    //cache the slider elements and setup a flag for success/failure
    var $sliders = $(this).find('.ui-slider-switch'),
        goNext   = true;

    //iterate through the sliders
    for (var i = 0, len = $sliders.length; i < len; i++) {

        //if this index's value is 'off' then set the success/failure flag to failure and stop the loop
        if ($sliders.eq(i).val() == 'off') {
            goNext = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    //if the success/failure loop is set to success then forward the user to the next page
    if (goNext === true) {
        $.mobile.changePage($('#next-page'));

    } else {
        //if the success/failure loop is set to failure then ...
    }

    //prevent the form from submitting normally
    return false;
});
```

Comment: @user1012535 You are welcome. Normally accepted answers are marked a such, here is some information about this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work